# iPad Safari Home Screen website gets stuck on Facebook Login

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website that uses the JavaScript SDK, and I have a facebook login button that calls `FB.login()` that opens a new tab for the user to log in.

This website is optimized for the iPad, and I made a home screen entry for this website so it could be viewed in full screen, like how this article mentions it:
http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/html-fullscreen-apps-for-the-ipad

My problem is that only in the home-screen-launched, fullscreen version, when I click on the login button, either I see a white screen, or I get the login details screen (but in that case, clicking "Log In" also results in a white screen), and thus I get to a dead end.

How do I make it so the Facebook login goes through and I get redirected back to my website successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple’s documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) for this says,

> When you use this standalone mode, Safari is not used to display the web content—specifically, there is no browser URL text field at the top of the screen or button bar at the bottom of the screen.

Sounds to me like this might also affect the ability to open popups. If that’s the case, you could maybe use the server-side authentication flow instead.

Comment: The facebook login popup does come out sometimes, like I said. Popups themselves do work. Or maybe popups actually take over their opener windows, and when they are closed, I am left with nothing?

Comment: Well, if you say popups in general work, it should be easy to prove or dismiss that: Open a popup of your own, click around in it a little, and then have it close by itself – is your original page you opened the popup from still there?